# Download Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1607

I want to update my windows 10 to the latest build 1607, I have 5 laptops at home which needs this update, I would like to download the ISO (or whatever the file extension is) and update them manually instead of downloading the same build 5 times, I found this [Windows 10 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history) but it gave me a desktop client app that downloads the same file, (like scratching your left ear with your right hand!), I want the actual update files maybe direct link or the location where this downloader stores the updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the ISO for Windows 10 v1607 from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/).

After downloading, mount the ISO and run `setup.exe` to start installing the Anniversary Update.

Comment: Wouldn't this download the whole windows, instead of only the updates?

Comment: It's the whole Windows. The update alone can't be downloaded as it;s major update (version upgrade)